# How to get returned file name

Tags: jquery, spring

I want to know the returned file name with jQuery

for example

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String getFirstPage(){
   return "/first/login"
}
```

If I execute the code above, it will return login.jsp file and the browser will fill the screen with the code of login.jsp

Is there any way to retrieve the file name(login.jsp) inside login.jsp's script tag??

Answer (score 0):

Using org.springframework.ui.ModelMap object you can pass any values from Spring controller to view page.

In your case to get filename in *.jsp page you can try following approach.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String getFirstPage( ModelMap  modalMap){
   modalMap.addAttribute("fileName","login.jsp");
   return "/first/login";
}
```

In your login.jsp file include modalmap attribute enclosed within **${/attribute name/}** (Example: `<h1>${fileName}</h1>` this will show your file name in browser)

To know more about the Modalmap refer this [link](https://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-how-to-access-modelmap-values-in-a-jsp/)